# Javascript Password Submit - Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, passwords

I am trying to set a password to a form. I basically want someone to type a password into a password field and hit submit and if the password is right, it redirects them to buybutton.php in the same window. If the password isn't right, a javascript alert pops up that says 'Password wrong'. I've tried to write out the Javascript but no action is happening when the button is clicked. What have I done wrong in my code below? Thanks for the help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body width="950" height="300" style="background-image:url('giftcard_bg.jpg');">
<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function goForit() {
      var passwd;
      passwd = this.document.giftForm.pass.value;
      if(passwd=="samsamsam"){
      window.open ('buybutton.php','_self',false)
      }
      else{
      alert('Password wrong');
      }
    }
</SCRIPT>
</head>


<div style="position:absolute; top:150px; left:285px; text-align:center;">
    <form id="giftForm">        
        <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Enter Secret Code" style="font-size:150%;"/>
        <br />
        <input type="button" onClick="goForit()" value="Submit" style="font-size:150%; margin-top:15px;" />                 
     </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hope you're not depending on this for any real security.

Comment: Just a FYI, the HTML is invalid: it's `<head></head> <body></body>`. You shouldn't nest `<head>` inside `<body>`.

Comment: Yeah @j08691, it's not necessarily a super secure thing, it's just a fun little promotion we're running so it's not really a huge deal if they see the password. Haha, this would definitely not be effective for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
passwd = this.document.giftForm.pass.value;
```

causes an error try

```
passwd = document.getElementById('pass').value;
```

You were missing a `;` too after window.open `('buybutton.php','_self',false)`

Answer (score 3):

You should use `document.getElementById('pass').value` instead of `this.document.giftForm.pass.value`

```
function goForit() {
  var passwd;
  passwd = document.getElementById('pass').value;
  if(passwd=="samsamsam"){
  window.open ('buybutton.php','_self',false)
  }
  else{
  alert('Password wrong');
  }
}
```

**Word of warning:**

But be aware! Everybody can see the source code and find the password!!!

Instead of this, you should send the form to the server, and in the server side, check if it's correct. If it's correct, redirect the user to buybutton.php, but sending him a cookie which authorises him to enter to that page. And that page should check if he has that cookie.

But I'm not an expert, if you want that you should make another question asking that.

Comment: Great thanks. For this it's not a big deal if someone looked at the source code. It's a real quick promotion we're doing and it's just a small discount we're giving people through it. I'll brush up on my server side password authorization because I believe it'll be something I'll need in the future. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
function goForit() {
      var passwd = document.getElementById("pass").value;
      if(passwd=="samsamsam"){
      window.open ('buybutton.php','_self',false)
      }
      else{
      alert('Password wrong');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Oriol and Rajeev's answer are correct.

Alternatively, you can do this:

change

```
passwd = this.document.giftForm.pass.value;
```

to

```
passwd = document.forms['giftForm'].pass.value;
```

Comment: your code will not work there is no "name" attribute in the input field

Comment: i am really sorry, your code is working fine, but i can put all the blame oo jQuery, we actually forgot core javascript